# Python - error handling

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to use a python script on a Pi and Windows to pull csv data hosted on an internal site however after a while of pulling the data ( on both linux and windows ) there seems to be a glitch where it doesn't process ( which im trying to figure out or have a work around for ) and my script fails with
**IndexError: list index out of range** which i'm assuming is because my script can't access the HTTP site - however if i run the application as soon as it fails it's fine and will run again and fail after a random amount of time usually ~ 2h

Here is a snip of the code i'm using: - All i want from the CSV is the last line of data

```
import csv
import time
import math
import subprocess
import datetime
import requests
from contextlib import closing


def exec_code():



     url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/daily.csv"
     l = []
     with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r: 
         reader = csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
         for index,line in enumerate(reader): #This iterates the file line by line which is memory efficient in case the csv is huge.
             if index < 0: #removes header if 1 adds header
                 l.append(line)
         if index > 1: # means the file has at least 3 lines
             l.append(line)


     #creates variables
         for row in l:
          Time = row[0]
          Temp = row[5]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        exec_code()
        time.sleep(60)
```

Is there a way instead of the application crashing when there is no indexes to sleep for 5 seconds and then try again?

thank you

Comment: You don't show the full error traceback, so we can't be certain which line it is from, but my guess is these lines `Time = row[0] Temp = row[5]` are probably the issue.  Check the number of elements before indexing.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Python error handling is best addressed with the try, except syntax.

```
try:
    whatever you are trying to do
except:
    do this on error
```

It sounds like you might need to use a while flag in conjunction with this, however, if you want Python to continue trying until success:

```
flag = False
while not flag:
    try:
        whatever you are trying to do
        flag = True
    except:
        do this on error
        time.sleep(5)
```